# how to declare a function with Matrix type argument in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I've written following code. In this code, I've declared `func` in `foo.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <Eigen>

void func(std::vector<int>, cv::Mat_<float>, Eigen::Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>&, Eigen::VectorXf&);
```

so, in `foo.cpp`:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "foo.h"
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <Eigen>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace Eigen;

void func(std::vector<int> gnd, cv::Mat_<float> _data, Eigen::Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> &A, Eigen::VectorXf &B)
{
//some code
}
```

but i have following error:

`'Dynamic': undeclared identifier`

`'RowMajor': undeclared identifier`

`'_Rows': invalid template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix', expected compile-time constant expression`

`'_Cols': invalid template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix', expected compile-time constant expression`

`'_Options': invalid template argument for 'Eigen::Matrix', expected compile-time constant expression`

How to fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it myself! I must add namespace `Eigen` before `Dynamic` and `RowMajor` in `foo.h`:

```
void func(std::vector<int>, cv::Mat_<float>, Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>&, Eigen::VectorXf&);
```